# Get the parameters of a generic type on typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, graph, typescript-generics

So, I don't know if this is possible in typescript, but here is what I want to do:

Use a class that receives a generic to create a GraphQL query

```
class BackendClient<T> {
    type: string
    endpoint: string
    query: Object
    constructor(type: string, endpoint: string, query: Object) {
        this.type = type
        this.endpoint = endpoint
        this.query = query
    }

    async doQuery(): Promise<T> {
        var data: string
        data = `${this.type} { ${this.endpoint}(`
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.query).forEach(element => {
            data += `${element}: ${this.query[element]},`
        })
        data += `) {`
        T.parameters.forEach(element => { 
            data += `${element},`
        })
        data += `} }`
        return await axios({
            url: constants.ApiUrl,
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                query: data
            }
        }) as T
    }
}
```

So for example, I have a code that do this

```
interface Search {
    title: string
}

interface Response {
    id: number
    title: string
    image_url: string
}

async function main() {
    var search: Search = { title: "a" }
    var client = new BackendClient<Response>('query', 'search', search)
    console.log(await client.doQuery())
}

main()
```

How do I get Response parameters on the BackendClient?

Comment: Can you elaborate? What does "get the parameters of the generic" mean to you exactly?

Comment: oh, sorry, for example, when I call the class I send a generic, which is T, that I send as a object for example, is it possible to get its parameters? like I get from a normal object

Comment: It's still not very clear what you're after. Can you add some code to the bottom of your question that details what data you'd like to get the from the generic? Show an example of the type being passed in to `BackendClient`, and then show the result you want to get if that type was passed in.

Answer (score 1):

Parameter is a pretty vague word in this context and it sort of depends on what your goal is here, but it sounds like you want to know what property names that the generic parameter has as and then use that in some other type?

If so, you can do that with `keyof`. That will get you a union of all the keys in in any object that has properties.

```
type Keys = keyof { a: 123, b: 'string', c: true } // 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
```

To add a method in your class that returns all the property names of your generic parameter, you can type that like so:

```
class BackendClient<T> {
    getGenericProperties(): (keyof T)[] {
        // skipping implementation
        return 'any' as any
    }
}

interface ResponseData {
    id: number
    title: string
    image_url: string
}

const client = new BackendClient<ResponseData>()
const properties = client.getGenericProperties()
// inferred type: ("id" | "title" | "image_url")[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=85#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCbANYFMB2ATAwiAlmgLgDwAqAfNAN4CwAUNPdAObL4DiayATjsAAqcB7AA5d8eCAAoAlAC5oElAE8BAM2jEpAbQC6lWgwPQA9EegREOIUJypG0HAFshIZA4JgxA1PsP1OLAFdOVGgAcjBURVDoSBjIn3oAX1pkmlobfC4VBGRoACVkCCEvCGQAEQ8wPToGHHQ5VACHACMuBOgxfBc5CHxuW3bHMGYAfSCQHr6bRhTaWmAS-GhQPFQlgF5oVGQAdzgEFAxsVaICopLyytJpecXoIUERTjFC6E2VggA6ZjYObj5HqJxNJjKYJAAiOrg6AAH2g4M6LmhcMhDmGyDGnBA4K02iAA)